# How can I match my passwords against Have I Been Pwned?

Tags: linux

OK, so I've downloaded [all the SHA-1 hashes from Have I Been Pwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords), exported everything from my password manager, and processed that into a file with one password per line. How do I match these files effectively?

Answer (score 4):

## Prerequisites

- `7z`, which should be in [the "p7zip" package](https://superuser.com/a/33147/2259).
- `sha1sum` and `shred`, which should be in the "coreutils" package.
- `grep` from the "grep" package.

## Process

1. Create a file with unique upper case password hashes, and a file with passwords and their corresponding hashes:

   ```
   sort -u passwords.txt | while read -r password
   do
       hash="$(printf '%s' "$password" | \
           sha1sum | \
           cut -d' ' -f1 | \
           tr 'a-f' 'A-F')"
       printf '%s\n' "$hash" >> hashes.txt
       printf '%s\t%s\n' "$hash" "$password" >> passwords-with-hashes.txt
   done
   ```
2. Match your hashes to all the entries in the downloaded file:

   ```
   7z e -so pwned-passwords-sha1-ordered-by-hash-v*.7z | \
   cut -c 1-40 | \
   grep -Fxf hashes.txt | \
   tee matches.txt
   ```

   Be patient - this took nearly 20 minutes on a desktop machine with an SSD!
3. Show the passwords related to the matches:

   ```
   grep -Ff matches.txt passwords-with-hashes.txt | cut -f2
   ```
4. Securely remove the files you've created:

   ```
   shred --remove hashes.txt matches.txt passwords.txt passwords-with-hashes.txt
   ```